# Quicksight parse date into 3 days

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, amazon-quicksight

I know Quicksight could help parse the time into DAY, WEEK, MONTH and YEAR in Field Wells, but how could I customize it into 3 days(72 hrs)? Is there any windowsFunction I could use?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a [calculated field](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/working-with-calculated-fields.html) with formula looking something like that:

```
addDateTime((extract("DD", {create_time})/3)*3, "DD", truncDate("DD", {create_time}))
```

And use it for grouping. Depends on your desired time interval it possibly will not do exactly what you need - cause it will group days in month by three, but you can use [dateDiff](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/dateDiff-function.html) and either some fixed date as starting point. For example:

```
addDateTime((dateDiff(parseDate("2020-01-01"), truncDate("DD", {create_time}))/3)*3, "DD", parseDate("2020-01-01"))
```